# Zcat multiple compressed files in a for loop

Tags: zcat

Im fairly new to bash scripting and i've been searching here in stackoverflow for an answer that will match what im looking for but cant find an exact match.. apologies if this has already been answered.

I have multiple folders that has multiple compressed files, some are gzip extension , some doesnt have extension.

The only way Ive been able to see the content of the compressed file is by doing

```
zcat filename.gzip > filename
```

My goal is to create a for loop that will :

1. zcat all files and output it to a new file & add an identifier at the end, something like "-read"
2. delete the compressed file

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decompress all files that `gzip` would handle using `find`, `basename` and a `while` loop:

```
find . -type f | while read f; do
    set -e # You should probably always script with set -e
           # This will cause the subshell to stop on errors.
    zcat < "$f" > "$f-new" || continue
    rm "$f"
done
```

This should also handle any weird quoting that comes up. The `while` loop will run in a subshell, and `set -e` will set the stop on error option in it so that if there's an error with either the `zcat` or the `rm` it won't keep plowing ahead destroying everything in sight.

Comment: this is what happens when i try to gunzip a single file. 

`
gunzip -d mambu.Clients_Meta000000000001.gzip
gzip: mambu.Clients_Meta000000000001.gzip: unknown suffix -- ignored
`

Comment: im getting an error **
gzip: mambu.Clients_Meta000000000001.gzip: unknown suffix -- ignored **

Comment: the only ways ive been able to get this to work were:

`
**gunzip < mambu.Clients.gzip > mambu.Clients**

or 

**zcat compressedfile > filename-read**
`

Comment: Brilliant, sorry for that. I've updated the answer to handle that extension instead.

Comment: Thank you! that worked for files that has .gzip in the filename. How do you do it for files that doesnt have that extension but of the same file type? 

What i mean is I have multiple files that dont have extension but the file type is=gzip compressed data

When I tried the last command, i was getting this.


```
$ find . -name 'mambu*' | while read f; do
>     set -e # You should probably always script with set -e
>            # This will cause the subshell to stop on errors.
>     zcat < "$f" > $(basename "$f")
> done

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file

```

Comment: Without a pattern to match, it's a bit more difficult. I'll see if I can update the question with something suitable.